# WIX : Install multiple instances of an application and upgrade the application if installed at previously installed location

Tags: wix, upgrade, wix3.7, wix3.8

I am able to install at user specified location but it uninstall previous version (either if it is installed in same directory or in different directory) , as I am performing major upgrade.

If I remove major upgrade then it creates independent instances but doesn't upgrade when overwriting existing instance.

**I want to create independent instance if there is no existing instance at the location of installation but upgrade existing version if there is existing instance at the location of installation.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install multiple instances of an MSI with dynamic instance name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620929/install-multiple-instances-of-an-msi-with-dynamic-instance-name)

Comment: Not actually because I also want to upgrade the application if there is existing instance at the location of installation.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt your situation handled by a major ugprade?

Thats what major upgrade is meant for. If your upgrade table is correctly configured, you can upgrade an older version of your application. If no older version is found, the application gets installed just like a fresh installation.

Or is there something more to this question that i am not seeing?

Comment: Its the matter of directory. I want to have multiple instances on same machine but if the application is already installed as an instance in the directory only then it should override it but not otherwise.

Comment: Major upgrade will uninstall the previous entry even if you will install the product in different directory with same upgradecode